# PHPExcel - validating success of write & save

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel

I have successfully got PHPExcel writing a beautiful, well-formed spreadsheet. My problem is what to do next. I need to perform some database updates if the file was written successfully and saved. These updates must not be made if the file has not been written.

I have searched around but can't find anything on this.

Here is my current 'write' code:

```
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $file['success'] = $objWriter->save($file['path'].$file['filename']);
```

The other parts of the $file array are specified elsewhere. This way I can pass the array as the function result and use the path & filename in other parts of my code. Currently $file['success'] debugs as NULL.

**edit: structure of methods within class**

```
    public function export_ap_files {

    //fetch data to go into the XLS file
    $data = $this->get_invoices_for_payment();

    //build excel files
    if ( !empty($data['ap_invoices']) ) {

                    //code to build the XLSX is in another method
        $ap_xls = $this->export_ap_excel($data['ap_invoices']);

        //mark invoices as sent for payment - if the XLSX file has not been written then this bit should not proceed
        foreach ($data['ap_invoices'] as $invoice) {

            //CakePHP save code goes here
        }

    }

    die('done');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel throws exceptions on failure, so wrap your code in a try/catch block

**EDIT**

```
// fetch data to go into the XLS file
$data = $this->get_invoices_for_payment();

// build excel files
if ( !empty($data['ap_invoices']) ) {

    try {
        // code to build the XLSX is in another method
        $ap_xls = $this->export_ap_excel($data['ap_invoices']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Failed to create Excel file: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    // mark invoices as sent for payment
    // if the XLSX file has not been written then this bit should not proceed
    foreach ($data['ap_invoices'] as $invoice) {

        //CakePHP save code goes here
    }
}

die('done');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not hugely familiar with try/catch. I have edited my entry above to show the general structure of the methods within my class - please can you advise where the try/catch needs to go?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Now to work out a way of forcing it to fail writing the file so I can test it :-)

Comment: Easiest option to trigger a failure: save file to a directory that you don't have privilege to write to